# What is the id that the calaba.sh-ios query gets based on?

Tags: ios, calabash-ios

When I use the query to pull the elements on the screen one of the attributes it gives me is id, however I can not find what determines its value. It is not the Restoration ID nor the Object ID. In some places it is the same as the background image name, others it is the class name, and most of the time it is nil.

I am try to find what is the id value that calaba.sh sees so I can set it in the app code to use as a unique identifier for my tests like I'm doing for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'id' is the `accessibilityIdentifier`.

It it is more usual, however, to search by `mark`.

On iOS a mark is:

- accessibilityIdentifier
- accessibilityLabel
- if the view responds to `text`, then the mark will be the text.

`query("view marked:'sign-in'")`